# How can I see data from all different ID3 versions on a file?

Tags: id3

I'm attempting to track down the source of [a problem](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=728) in Clementine (an audio player) that I thinks stems from having differing ID3v1 and ID3v2 tags on files.  My problem is that I can't find an application that displays *both* sets of data.

I'll take either an application or a library.  Runnable on Linux is preferred, but Windows is acceptable.

Comment: "A problem" => public 403.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it was probably [this issue](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/728).

Answer (score 1):

Bulk ID3 will do what you're looking for.  Use the `--print-only` flag.  Keep in mind the current release is an Alpha.  Be sure to read the README.txt file in the download.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bulkid3/

Andrew